# How to detect mouse input in ecto?

Tags: ros, ecto

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Ecto Gurus,

I have run through the various parts of the Ecto Kitchen (very cool!) and have succeeded in getting basic feature detection to work using both a webcam and a Kinect.  I would like to be able to select rectangular regions on an imshow window with a mouse and use the selected region as a mask for feature detection.  This is something that can be done with OpenCV using the SetMouseCallback() function.  I tried that alongside the ecto code in my Python script, but it doesn't seem to fire when clicking and dragging on the ecto imshow window.

Is there a way to do this?  I see the 'trigger' parameter for keyboard input but I'm not sure if this can be adapted for mouse input.

Thanks!

patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28568/how-to-detect-mouse-input-in-ecto?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2012-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

maybe the easiest here is to have a different thread dealing with your input. That is how pressed keys are figured out in imshow. Look at :

https://github.com/plasmodic/ecto_opencv/blob/master/cells/opencv/highgui/imshow.cpp

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-04-25**:
Thanks @Vincent Rabaud.  I'll take a look.